# Change datetime format within CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, date, time

I hope you might be able to give some advice. I'm trying to create a table within SQL Server 2008 and I need to update my `DateTime` column to a different format.

```
CREATE TABLE #History (Tag nvarchar(512), User nvarchar(40), DateTime datetime, Quality int)
```

However I need to make the `DateTime` column return a `DateTime` value in the following format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd THH:mm:ss
```

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give.

Comment: why you want it like that???

Comment: `DATETIME` in SQL Server has **no format** - it's a binary, 8-byte value. The only thing you see is a **string representation** of `DATETIME`, and that can be changed by using `SET DATEFORMAT ...`

Comment: `datetime`s don't *have* a format. They just store the data (using an internal, undocumented format, but it's basically a floating point number). If you need a particular format, you ask for that format when you convert from a `datetime` to a *string*

Comment: I'm working with a Reporting Package that requires date time formats to match the format above. If any date/time values are returned in a different format it is not recognised.

Comment: Yes, so you write `CONVERT(varchar(20),[DateTime],126)` in the `SELECT` clause of the query that's feeding this report package.

Answer (score 0):

There's no dateformat there's only the binary data!

Your date data is persisted as bunch of 0 and 1 and got no format at all.
when you retrieve that data, let's say in a select the query analyzer ill show you a representation of that data, by default a ISO formated datetime.

If anything consuming that result set needs a specif date format you can use cast/convert or set dateformat (and language) to achieve that.

See Damien comment for a good example.